# How do I add remove picture from storage, and change value in DB with a button

Tags: php, laravel

I have remove button on profile page on my website. I want it to remove image from the storage and also change value in database 'person' in a field 'avatar' to default.png.

I tried to add action to my button which references to routes and uses deleteImage function from controller. Everything is included in code.

Button in my code, for image deletion:

```
<a href="" action="{{$person->last_name}}/delete" id="" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light active" name="delete-image" id="delete-image-button">
<i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i></a>
```

web.php with routes:

```
Route::get('/person/profile/{person_id}/{last_name}/delete', 'Views\Person\PersonViewController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
```

function in `PersonViewController.php`:

```
function deleteImage($id)
    {
        $name = Person::where('person_id', $id)->get('avatar');
        if(Storage::delete('/files/assets/images/user-profile/' . $name, '/files/assets/images/user-profile/standard/' . $name, '/files/assets/images/user-profile/miniatures/' . $name) && Person::where('person_id', $id)->update(['avatar' => 'default.png'])) {
            return view('person.profile.profile-view')->with('success', 'Image Deleted Successfully');
        }
        else{
            return view('person.profile.profile-view')->with('fail','Something Went Wrong');
        }
    }
```

I want the button to delete images stored in 3 folders `/files/assets/images/user-profile/`, `/files/assets/images/user-profile/standard`, `/files/assets/images/user-profile/mimiature`
and also change value in database from `imagename` to `default.png`

Comment: did you try `@unlink('filepath/filename')`?

Comment: @unlink('filepath/filename') for deleting file, you already have save feature for saving new one and update query so new name or id change in db

Comment: yeah I tried unlink, still I think the button doesnt sned the request correctly or sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

**can you change function name like this,**`function deleteImage($id, $lastName)` **then comment all codes in function, then put** 
`$variables = [$id, $lastName]
dd($variables)`.